# Overlays in VideoStream

Tags: android, opencv

I want to develop an app where I stream a video. Instead of showing the images directly, I want to add graphics. Therefore I need to capture each frame and process it before it is shown to viewer.

My approach is to use OpenCV to do the rendering. I do not know if that is the best choice. Further, currently I have working code where the native camera is used and I get `AImage *` in a loop.

Which approach is best, trying to attach the data in `AImage` to a `cv::Mat` and then go back? Or start a videostream using `VideoCapture`?

If starting `VideoCapture` is the best choice, should it be started in native code or in `java`?

Comment: Do you need to add the graphics to the video directly, or to save the video with the graphics added? If not it may be easier and less processing overhead to show the graphics on a separate overlay on top of the video.

Comment: The goal is to live-stream the video on youtube for example.

Comment: Ok, sounds like you do need a solution to actually embed the graphics in the video. There was some discussion about having separate graphics tracks in mp4 videos, similar to subtitles tracks, some years ago, but I'm not sure where that is at.